# Clip polygon with nothing more than a point as starting point

Tags: qgis, arcmap, buffer, clip

Quite a straightforward question:

I have a point layer that consists of a few thousand points. These points are heterogeneously positioned in or very close to polygons that are water bodies. These polygons differ in size. I would like to cut the polygon based on the location of these points.

Please look at the example below. Blue polygon (water body) and black point is what I have right now. The purple, red or green lined polygon (or line) is a example of what the result can look like in order to clip the blue polygon. Which approach do you suggest?

Perhaps that a buffer around a point would help. The tricky part is that the buffer should match the two closest edges of the surrounding polygon. Or maybe to create a line to both sides?

[image]

Other suggestions?

Working with both QGIS and GIS (arcmap 10.0)

Comment: Can you add an image depicting your desired result?

Comment: Certainly! Hopefully this clarifies it.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  By asking how to do the same thing in either of two products you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad for focused Q&A.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased the question wrong. The purple, red or green lined polygon (or line) is what the results can look like. I do not have a specific preference. Would like to know how to approach this.

Comment: I assume the blue polygons differ in size? So a buffer would not always fit the polygons?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Are those points placed equidistant?

Comment: No the points are positioned more or less randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for QGIS,

I propose to act on the following scenario,

"while I am kind :-)",

If I understand you correctly, the initial situation is as shown in Figure 1 and my test layers are called "pts" and "polygon_exp".
[image]

**Action 1**, using the `new virtual layer` with the SQL script in the form window add 2 layers to the screen form and run the SQL script
see Figure 2.
[image]

```
SELECT ShortestLine(a.geometry, b.geometry) geom FROM pts a, polygon_exp b
```

result is shown in Figure 3
[image]

save it by giving it a new name.

**Action 2**, using 
on the result of Action 1 start the geoinstrument, see Figure 4
[image]

The result is shown in Figure 5.

[image]

**Action 3**, using  cut your pond with the result obtained in Action 2, see Figure 6
[image]

and see Figure 7 for the result:
[image]

Quite a straightforward question :-)...

We've all reached our goal, before we meet again...

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Are you answering philosophical or geo related questions ?! 

Comment: @Taras, Try not to burn out in life, i.e. not to burn out emmotionally, it's very important... it's the philosophy of life... Try to do what develops you and what interests you...

Comment: Great! Thanks for the elaborate response to this "straightforward question"

Comment: I'm pleased that this solution is clear to you and most importantly, that one of the solutions to your question...